# Hibernate criteria for get records which have year 2012

Tags: oracle, hibernate

i need all records which have year entered from search criteria.
for ex:
String year = "2012";

In hibernate it work for

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("createDate", "%"+year+"%"));
```

createDate is in format DD-MM-YY.

Please suggest..

Comment: What is the errors ? Please post the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("createDate", "%2012%", MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

But I would prefer changing your db field to a date format(its string at the moment?) and performing a greater than comparison (instead of like).

Comment: so use greater than or equal to 1 Jan 2012 and less than 1-jan-2013

Answer (score 0):

`like` only applies for the String . For the date field , you can use `Restrictions.between()` to generate `between '01/01/2012 00:00:00' and '12/31/2012 23:59:59'` for the where clause

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date fromDate = df.parse("1-1-2012 00:00:00");
Date toDate = df.parse("31-12-2012 23:59:59");

criteria.add(Restrictions.between("createDate", fromDate, toDate));
```

Also , please note that all the properties used in the Criteria  API is the Java property name , but not the actual column name.