# search record using year criteria in hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I need all records which have year entered from search criteria.

for ex: String year = "2012";

In hibernate how it work ?

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("createDate", "%"+year+"%"));
```

createDate is fetch in format DD-MM-YY from oracle database.

Please suggest..

Comment: Is `createDate` in Oracle a `DATE`?  Or a `VARCHAR2`?  If it is a `DATE`, it has no format-- dates in Oracle will always be stored in a packed binary format that is not human readable.

Comment: yes createDate in Oracle a DATE. it fetch in DD-MM-YY format.but i want search record on bases of full year like if i select year 2011 or 2012 or 2009 like that. is there any parsing method in hibernate for same ? i have some other criteria also..so i can not use sql query.

Comment: I don't think there are any differences between the questions you ask yesterday : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973730/hibernate-criteria-for-get-records-which-have-year-2012/9974789#9974789 .They are the same IMO.

Comment: This query is working for oracle Data base but not for mysql may i know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("to_char({alias}.CREATE_DATE, 'yyyy') = ?", year, Hibernate.STRING));
```

I'm assuming that the name of the column mapped to `createDate` is `CREATE_DATE`

Comment: what should i pass in alias ? here create date can be 01-10-12 or 02-12-08 like that..

Comment: `The {alias} placeholder with be replaced by the row alias of the queried entity` see here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html (you might want to try it without the `{alias}.` part as well)

Comment: as @JustinCave said - an Oracle Date hasn't got a format. You can format it when converting to a String with `to_char`, in my answer I took only the 4 digits year from the date. If you query a date (ie in sqlplus) you get it as a string formatted by NLS_DATE_FORMAT which is probably `DD-MM-YY` in your case, it doesn't mean that there is no "4 digit year"

Comment: updated my answer: You need to give the DB column name instead of `createDate`. so the code should be something like `{alias}.CREATE_DATE`

Comment: It works for me, are you sure `CREATE_DATE` is a Date ? can you show the sql generated by hibernate ?

Comment: query is : select this_.VRH_JOB_STATE as VRH41_14_0_ from VWS_OWNER.MV_VAL_REP_SEARCH this_ where to_char(this_.CREATE_DATE, 'YY') like ?;

Comment: Mapping part as: <property name="createDate" type="java.lang.String"> <column name="CREATE_DATE" length="7" /> in database CREATE_DATE is date field.

Comment: a) you need to use `'yyyy'` and not `'yy'` as you want to compare to a String with **4** digits year and not **2** (2012 and not 12). b) why do you use `like` and not `=` ?